# Play animation once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a simple animation for my dishwashing machine in 3dsmax. I imported the object as an fbx file into Unity. The animation is called "openandclose". The animation itself opens and closes the machine.

However I can't seem to find a way to trigger the animation to happen once at the click of a button. How can I do this?

Comment: Searh for animator and animation in unity.you can simply add an animation to your machine.adding triggers are also so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity has a great documentation regarding every core function including animations. Check this link out:
 http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html

and to get the button pressed:
http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

combined it would be something like this i guess:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        animation.Play("openandclose");

}
```